# How can I update current time of the video while it's playing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

Every second it goes after started playing the video, I want it to run the function which is called **showComments**

To make sure it's running every second, I just added

```
alert(getCurrentTime().toFixed());
```

However, it's not even running :(

How can I make this run **showComments** function every second?

Here's the demo and codes.

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f0buajyz/

```
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '270',
            width: '480',
            videoId: 'mzIdhSTHJts',
        });
    }


    var fixedTimeHtml5Youtube = 0;

    function getStatus(){
        if(player.getCurrentTime().toFixed() != fixedTimeHtml5Youtube){
            alert(getCurrentTime().toFixed());
            showComments(player.getCurrentTime().toFixed());
            fixedTimeHtml5Youtube = player.getCurrentTime().toFixed();
        }  
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to run the function every 1000ms(1s), in combination with the `onStateChange` event.
Whenever the event fires, it checks if the video is playing. If its playing, it starts calling the `showComments` function every second. Otherwise it stops the interval.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crisbeto/f0buajyz/4/

HTML:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

JavaScript:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
var player = null;
var interval = null;

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
document.body.appendChild(tag);    


window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function(){
    player = new window.YT.Player(document.getElementById('player'), {
        height: '270',
        width: '480',
        videoId: 'mzIdhSTHJts',
        events: {
            onStateChange: function(event){
                callback(event);
            }
        }
    });
}

function callback(event){
    var playerStatus = event.data;

    // player is playing
    if(playerStatus === 1){
        interval = setInterval(showComments, 1000);
        // player is stopped
    }else if(interval){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}

function showComments(){
    document.getElementById('output').value += "\n showComments called.";
}
```

Comment: your code  runs showComments even if the video is not playing:( player.getCurrentTime() is youtube's API and it gives me current_time of the video so that I'd like to use it then I can get accurate current time of the video.

Comment: @HUSTEN I've updated my answer with a better solution.

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't work at all:( could you show me if it works okay with using jsfiddle?

Comment: @HUSTEN I've updated the example with a proper fiddle. Here's the link https://jsfiddle.net/crisbeto/f0buajyz/3/